# Excel VBA Selecting Records from Access Database Not Pulling Correctly

Tags: sql, vba

I have a macro that pulls from an Access DB and writes the recordset to the spreadsheet based upon dates that are entered into a userform. However, if I enter in "3/2/2105" and "3/5/2015" it returns all the records from 3/2-3/5 and then 3/20-3/31. I cannot think of any reason why it would do this. If anybody could point me in the right direction/make suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub pullfrommsaccess()

    queryform.Show

    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim AccessFile As String
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim startdate As String
    Dim enddate As String
    Dim i As Integer


    Sheet2.Cells.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    AccessFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "mdidatabase.accdb"


    On Error Resume Next
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccessFile


If tblname = "Attainments" Then
    If shift1 = "1" Then
        SQL = "SELECT [Line],[Area],[Shift],[Attainment Percentage],[Date] FROM " & tblname & " WHERE Shift='1' and Date Between " & "'" & pastdate & "' " & "and" & " '" & currentdate & "'"
    End If
    If shift2 = "2" Then
        SQL = "SELECT [Line],[Area],[Shift],[Attainment Percentage],[Date] FROM " & tblname & " WHERE Shift='2' and Date Between " & "'" & pastdate & "' " & "and" & " '" & currentdate & "'"
    End If
    If shift1 = "1" And shift2 = "2" Then
        SQL = "SELECT [Line],[Area],[Shift],[Attainment Percentage],[Date] FROM " & tblname & " WHERE Date Between " & "'" & pastdate & "' " & "and" & " '" & currentdate & "'"
    End If
End If

If tblname = "MDItable" Then
    If shift1misses = "1" Then
        SQL = "SELECT [Date],[Area],[Shift],[Line],[Quantity],[Issue] FROM " & tblname & " WHERE Shift='1' and Date Between " & "'" & pastdatemisses & "' " & "and" & " '" & currentdatemisses & "'"
    End If
    If shift2misses = "2" Then
        SQL = "SELECT [Date],[Area],[Shift],[Line],[Quantity],[Issue] FROM " & tblname & " WHERE Shift='2' and Date Between " & "'" & pastdatemisses & "' " & "and" & " '" & currentdatemisses & "'"
    End If
    If shift1misses = "1" And shift2misses = "2" Then
        SQL = "SELECT [Date],[Area],[Shift],[Line],[Quantity],[Issue] FROM " & tblname & " WHERE Date Between " & "'" & pastdatemisses & "' " & "and" & " '" & currentdatemisses & "'"
    End If

End If



    On Error Resume Next
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set conn = Nothing
        MsgBox "Recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


    rs.CursorLocation = 3
    rs.CursorType = 1

    rs.Open SQL, conn


    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
        rs.Close
        conn.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set conn = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i


    'Copy From RecordSet to Excel and Reset
    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing



    MsgBox "The records from " & pastdate & " and " & currentdate & " were successfully retrieved from the '" & tblname & "' table!", vbInformation, "Done"
End If



Call TrimALL

End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd suggest you drop `alllowercase` and adopt a `camelCase` naming convention for your locals, and `PascalCase` for procedure names. Readability++

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know I'm pretty bad about making my code pretty, Im the only one who looks at it at my job usually haha

Answer (score 1):

You have a field named Date, try renaming that and reworking the code as in first instance that's a reserved word and is a bad idea for starters!

When working with dates, see Allen Browne's comments on the matter here for consistency;
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

You have your dates declared as string, but in your SQL query you're surrounding them with a ' not a #. It should read;

```
Date Between " & "#" & pastdate & "# " & "and" & " #" & currentdate & "#"
```

All of the above should sort you out, if not comment and I'll take a much closer look for you!

Comment: I implemented the code and it still didn't work :/ I think the field named Date is fine, because of the brackets surrounding it, which has worked fine in past projects. Thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it!